# How to decompress String in Java which is compressed in VBA using zlib

Tags: java, excel, dll, vba

We are working on a VBA project. In that project we compress the string using zlib.dll and send request to the server. On the server we can't decompress that buffer.

following code which i used in java to uncompress the string

```
 public static String decompress(byte[] str) throws IOException {
     ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(str);
        InflaterInputStream iis = new InflaterInputStream(bais);

        String result = "";
        byte[] buf = new byte[5];
        int rlen = -1;
        while ((rlen = iis.read(buf)) != -1) {
            result += new String(Arrays.copyOf(buf, rlen));
        }

        // now result will contain "Hello World!"

        System.out.println("Decompress result: " + result);
        return result;
    }
```

My Question is how can I decompress the string on the server in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `java.util.zip` provides classes to manage compressed data. [java.util.zip.Inflater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html) may be useful in your case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i tried that but it shows the error incorrect header check

Comment: please, could you post what you have try so far? (a sample of a compressed input may be useful too)

Comment: yes in vba first i compressed after that convert to byte after that i encode it then send a request to server on a server first i decode it then try to uncompress but it shows me error incorrect header check

Comment: please, post a snippet of the Java code you're using.

Comment: public static String decompress(byte[] str) throws IOException {
   ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(str);
         InflaterInputStream iis = new InflaterInputStream(bais);

         String result = "";
         byte[] buf = new byte[5];
         int rlen = -1;
         while ((rlen = iis.read(buf)) != -1) {
             result += new String(Arrays.copyOf(buf, rlen));
         }

         // now result will contain "Hello World!"

         System.out.println("Decompress result: " + result);
         return result;
     }

Comment: Your code works fine:

byte[] compressedData = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64("eNrzSM3JyVcozy/KSVEEAB0JBF4=");

        System.out.println( decompress(compressedData));

(Prints "Hello world!").  

Could you post a sample of your compressed data?

Comment: this is my encoded string in vba: MzQ6eJzLSqxMSU0tSMpPSkxJdUjPTczM0UvOz2U0YHRxDfZ092NkBADbkgrl

Comment: and this is my compressed string using zlib.dll in vba:
34:xœËJ¬LIM-HÊOJLIuHÏMÌÌÑKÎÏe4`tq
öt÷cd Û’